# Stardate blog date

Tags: wordpress, date

Is it possible to have date on the Wordpress blog in the form of [stardate](http://plaza.ufl.edu/joec/startrek_stardate_system_explained.htm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course!

Just add a PHP function to [calculate stardate](http://reusablecode.blogspot.com/2009/01/stardate.html) to your theme's functions.php and call it to display the date in your theme instead of `the_date()`

Comment: It's good but I didn't get what stardate format it's using. I found a [WP plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/stardate/) that gives an option to display it in to date formats... Thanks for your help...

Comment: I'm not that much of a trekkie and not aware of multiple stardates. If you are using some mixup of the current date (no calculation), you could simply adjust your WordPress settings.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend doing it on client side write javascript date to stardate converter. Something like [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/stardates.shtml)

Comment: Finding all the dates to translate with JavaScript would be futile. Pun intended :)

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't clear in my question, I meant display date when the post was made. This script is great and simple for displaying current time. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

There's actually already a plugin to do that > [Stardate Plugin](http://seoserpent.com/wordpress/stardate)

Comment: Already posted that [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681428/stardate-blog-date/9186929#comment10795117_8681453). Thanks anyway.